# Netty Set Content-Length Automatically

Tags: java, http, netty, reactor-netty

I want Netty (Reactor Netty, to be specific) to set the `Content-Length` header in my requests. Currently, even when I send a request body in my request, the `Content-Length` header is not set. Is it possible to configure `Netty` to set this automatically (set it to `0` if there is no request body)? `Postman` does this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the content that you want to send. If it is of type `Mono`, then we will calculate the content length and send a `FullHttpMessage`. If it is of type `Flux`, we will consider this as a chunked content and thus we will not calculate the content length.
Here is an example with `Mono`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String response =
        HttpClient.create()
                .wiretap(true)
                .post()
                .uri("https://postman-echo.com/post")
                .send(Mono.just(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer("something".getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()))))
                .responseContent()
                .aggregate()
                .asString()
                .block();
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

In the logs you should be able to see this:

```
17:01:46.813 [reactor-http-nio-4] DEBUG reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient - [id: 0x668bd78f, L:/xxx:xxx - R:postman-echo.com/34.239.20.132:443] WRITE: 118B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 50 4f 53 54 20 2f 70 6f 73 74 20 48 54 54 50 2f |POST /post HTTP/|
|00000010| 31 2e 31 0d 0a 75 73 65 72 2d 61 67 65 6e 74 3a |1.1..user-agent:|
|00000020| 20 52 65 61 63 74 6f 72 4e 65 74 74 79 2f 64 65 | ReactorNetty/de|
|00000030| 76 0d 0a 68 6f 73 74 3a 20 70 6f 73 74 6d 61 6e |v..host: postman|
|00000040| 2d 65 63 68 6f 2e 63 6f 6d 0d 0a 61 63 63 65 70 |-echo.com..accep|
|00000050| 74 3a 20 2a 2f 2a 0d 0a 63 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d |t: */*..content-|
|00000060| 6c 65 6e 67 74 68 3a 20 39 0d 0a 0d 0a 73 6f 6d |length: 9....som|
|00000070| 65 74 68 69 6e 67                               |ething          |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I can answer this question for netty.... In netty this is not done automatically and the only way how to do it is to either set it your self or add a `ChannelOutboundHandler` that does it depending on the `FullHttpMessage` it receives.

Comment: Hey @Norman thanks for the response. I am trying it. Will update on this.

Comment: Can you point me to some resource on how to add handlers to my request pipeline? Thanks, extremely new to Netty here.

Comment: in netty it is just a matter of calling `pipeline.addLast(...)`. Not sure how it works with reactor-natty tho.